# Django admin weirdness (intermittently missing "admin" in URL)

Tags: django, admin

Sorry if someone recognizes this question, but I couldn't locate it anywhere.

I have been experimenting with django sites and have recently seen a problem where the first time I login to the admin interface, the links in the admin table are all missing the "/admin/" portion of the URL. However, if I logout and back in, or if I manually add the "/admin/" portion to the URL, it works fine. For example, the "auth" link will come up as "locahost/auth" instead of "localhost/admin/auth".

I have debugged the sites.py and index.html template and see that the same url is passed in on both the first and second login. I don't quite understand why this is happening. It did not always happen, but I have not been able to figure out what I did to cause it.

I should also mention, it happens independent of the browser I use to access it and it happens whether I am using the django development server or an apache server.

Anybody got some thoughts on what I should look at?  Thanks.

Comment: I actually reduced my urls.py to the single pattern:

Comment: Sorry, hit return too quickly.  I only have the pattern url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)) in my urls.py.

Comment: So I double checked my urls.py to make sure that I retyped the line properly. Seems I actually had a pattern match of '^admin$' without the trailing slash. When I changed it to match what I typed above, I get more predictable and expected behavior. Thought I had gone over that file, but I apparently read too quickly. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this out. The problem was that I had a bad url pattern match for the admin views. I had a pattern of `'^admin$'` instead of `'^admin/'`.